# How to split a table without header into 6 columns

Tags: html, css, reactjs, grid

I want to design a table of 5 columns with no heading as below:

[image]

I'm not getting the correct way of doing it.
The data comes from endpoint and will be of 30 items.
I want ideally to display using `map` operator.

Data array:

```
[
    {
        "date": "1 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "2 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "3 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "4 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "5 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "6 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "7 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "8 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "9 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "10 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "11 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "12 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "13 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "14 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "15 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "16 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "17 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "18 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "19 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "20 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "21 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "22 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "23 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "24 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "25 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "26 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "27 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "28 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "29 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "30 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    }
]
```

I was thinking of splitting the array into array of 5 items but I think there will be a simpler approach for this.
I was also looking at dividing it as col-md-2 but I'm not clear how to split into 5 columns.

Comment: Have you tried to use display grid?

Comment: @Singh Yes. But how to split to second row after 5th element?

Comment: Try grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;

Comment: "*...data comes from endpoint and will be of 30 items.*" - but what about February, and those months - January, March, May, July, August, October, and December - with 31 days?

Comment: @DavidThomas Doesn't matter. it will always be 30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display grid should do the work like this :

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;

const Example = ({title}) => {
    const data = [
    {
        "date": "1 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "2 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "3 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "4 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "5 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "6 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "7 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "8 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "9 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "10 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "11 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "12 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "13 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "14 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "15 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "16 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "17 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "18 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "19 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "20 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "21 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "22 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "23 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "24 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "25 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "26 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "27 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "28 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "29 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    },
    {
        "date": "30 Nov 2022",
        "day": "Wednesday"
    }
]
  
    return (
        <div style={{display:"grid", gridTemplateColumns:"1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr"}}>
            {data.map(v=>(<p key={v.date} style={{border:'1px solid',margin:"0px"}}>{v.date}</p>))}
        </div>
    );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <Example title="Example using Hooks:" />
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>



<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This works on layouting. But how to make it responsive

Comment: Can't this be achieved using a table without header?

Comment: @Noel you can use media queries to make it responsive or container queries. Note on small screens you have to change the columns number as i think its quite impossible that 5 columns fit in small screens. Or you can make it scrollable if you don't want to change the columns size.
Also yes, this also can be achieved with tables.